# Apex Authorization error during installing app in Profession Edition

Tags: apex, managed-package, case, professional-edition, authorization

We are trying to install an app (manged package that already passed sf security review) in **Profession Edition**. But it is giving "**Apex is not supported in Professional Edition**" error. We want to raise a case for this. Please let us know, in which  category it should fall

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Partner-Portal-Case-Creation-Tips&language=en_US

Please let us know if there is another procedure to install app in Profession Edition.

Thanks,

Comment: Interesting...Looking for suggestions from the community.

Comment: I think you may want to contact the provider of that app, but if it relies on functionality that isn't supported in your org, you'll most likely not be able to run it. Or you'd need to upgrade your salesforce org license.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help

Building for 'Group Edition' and 'Professional Edition' there are some things to keep in mind:

- Professional Edition doesn't support web service calls unless the org is API enabled
- Permission sets are not available in in Professional Edition, and including them in a package can cause issues uninstalling a package from a Professional Edition org.
- Use of @RemoteAction calls aren't limited in the same way, so they're advisable for supporting Professional Edition.
- Some types of Dashboards aren't supported in Group Edition and can limit the user from installing into their org.
- Sharing rules and Profiles are not supported in the same way in Professional Edition
- Some objects such as Campaigns are not included in these editions by default.
- You should always attempt to install your app into a Professional Edition and Group Edition org before releasing it to the AppExchange in order to confirm it's inter-operability so that users coming in from the AppExchange don't encounter issues.

[Here is link for more Described Doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Can-I-develop-apex-code-in-developer-edition-and-deploy-it-to-professional-edition-1327107568004&language=en_US)

Courtesy - @jordan.baucke

Comment: Thanks for reply.
App developed by us already passed the security review. We are getting error "Apex is not supported in Professional Edition" while installing app in Professional edition. We think that we need to raise a case in Partner Portal for this.

Please let us know which category and sub-category need to be selected for raising case-

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Partner-Portal-Case-Creation-Tips&language=en_US